# passing a Spring Exception to a Thymeleaf page

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Having added the `error.html` Thymeleaf template to replace the default error page on Spring how can I get access to the exception on that page?

So I have custom exception thrown on some controller. How to access that exception on the Thymeleaf page?

I want this to work globally, so any controller thrown exception should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: For customized error pages with spring default error info**

There are some predefined objects in Thymeleaf to show error information, e.g. `${error}`, `${exception}` and so on. These objects can be used in your customized error page.

This article will help you more. [Custom Error Page with Thymeleaf](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-error-page-with-thymeleaf)

**Case 2: For customized error pages with customized error info**

There are `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` used to handle exceptions in controllers globally. A certain exception can be add to Modal's attribute and therefore accessed in thymeleaf templates. However,  please be noted that the solution does not work in `Webflux`.

The blog shows details about the solution. [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Doesn't cut it. I want to access the actual Exception object.

Comment: In this case, you may try to use `@ControllerAdvice` together with `@ExceptionHandler`. [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Yeah, `@ControllerAdvice` sounds what I need. Thanks. Add new/edit your answer for including the gist of the solution?